# Execute next from method

Tags: ruby

This code:

```
def skip_if_three(count)
    puts 'three detected, let\'s skip this loop!' if count == 3
end

5.times do |count|
    skip_if_three(count)
    puts count
end
```

returns:

```
0
1
2
three detected, let's skip this loop!
3                                                           # don't want this to appear!
4
```

However, if utilize the next keyword and do this:

```
def skip_if_three(count)
    next if count == 3
end

5.times do |count|
    skip_if_three(count)
    puts count
end
```

I get this SyntaxError:

> Invalid next

which was sort of expected. But how do I use `next` from a helper?

*Update*

I'm using nested loops and need to execute my check in each loop, so I want to keep it DRY, hence the external method.

```
5.times do |i|
    skip_if_three(i)
    puts count

    5.times do |j|
         skip_if_three(j)
         puts count
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def skip_if_three(count)
  return unless count == 3
  puts "three detected, let's skip this loop!"
  throw(:three)
end

5.times do |count|
  catch(:three) do
    skip_if_three(count)
    puts count
  end
end
```

result:

```
0
1
2
three detected, let's skip this loop!
4
```

---

```
def three?(count)
  return unless count == 3
  puts "three detected, let's skip this loop!"
  true
end

5.times do |count|
  puts count unless three?(count)
end
```

result:

```
0
1
2
three detected, let's skip this loop!
4
```

---

```
def three?(count)
  return unless count == 3
  puts "three detected, let's skip this loop!"
  true
end

5.times do |count|
  next if three?(count)
  puts count
end
```

result:

```
0
1
2
three detected, let's skip this loop!
4
```

Comment: @Starkers Is there anything about this answer that does not meet your requirement?

Comment: Seems great, just wondering if there's an even better way to do it. It seems I have to repeat the `next if three?(count)` inside each loop. Just wondering if that could be a little DRYer, and a bit nicer to just place a method call inside each loop rather than a operator, but if this is the best way to do it without some antipattern workaround then that's fine

Comment: I see. Then, you should create a method that not only skips if the number is three, but does the puts if it is not three.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to redesign the code blocks so that you don't have this issue. Hiding functionality like `next` isn't ideal, so something like this would retain the concision of your mockup code while making it clear what's actually going on:

```
def is_three? count
  count == 3
end

5.times do |count|
  next if is_three? count
  puts count
end
```

Comment: Seems okay, but I'm using nested loops in my actual code, with each loop having this next functionality. Is the repetition of `next if is_three? count` in each nested loop ideal?

Comment: This is a fascinating question, one that I've not thought about before.  @sawa has given an interesting answer, one that readers might find useful in other situations (and other innovative answers may yet be offered).  Are there other ways the OP's ultimate objective could be accomplished?  Of course--you have given one--but that is not what was asked. I agree that sometimes it is appropriate to suggest alternate approaches, but when the question is as specific and novel as this one, I think answers should be confined to the question at hand.

Comment: Well, `next` is a keyword, and you can't call a keyword from a method call down the stack, so the real answer is "it's impossible, but try...". `next if ...` is more clear about what's happening. (`throw`/`catch` seems to me to be the `GOTO` of Ruby.) Six months down the line when it's time to do some code archeology, I'll take clarity over innovation.